# how to debug web application deployed on tomcat from eclipse?

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT. i have deployed .war in tomcat. now i would like to debug it from eclipse.Please help me how to configure the steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug through eclipse you must have run tomcat in debug mode.
So first of all set following params in catlina file in bin as

set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
set JPDA_ADDRESS=5050

Then run tomcat server by using one of the following command from respective directory

..\jakarta-tomcat-5.5.7\bin>catalina jpda run
...or...
..\jakarta-tomcat-5.5.7\bin>catalina jpda start

I am using "jakarta-tomcat-5.5.7".

Then go 2 eclipse and setup for debug mode

in left tab select remote java application then select your respective project and set your connection properties.

Now you can debug.

Answer (score 2):

Actually to debug web app remotely you have to add the following command lien options to tomcat: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` or run it using command line: `catalina jpda start`

Take a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing) for details. Then you should connect to debug port using Eclipse (Run/Debug Configurations/Remote Java Application). But you are using GWT, so the better way to debug it is to refer to the GWT manual. GWT has a beautiful set of debugging [tools](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html).